# create a select and populating it using a php function, after pressing a button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been trying a lot of things, but I dont get the solution.

I have a form which has this structure:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="nombre">
<input type="submit" name="first submit">
<input type="text" name="address">
</form>
```

when I submit on "first submit"... I want to put on that form, a select, which will be populated with the results of a php function (passing the "name" as function variable)

the php function, receives the name written and returns an array, which needs to be looped, to get every element  as an option of the select

the form at the end need to look as:

```
<form mode="post" action="somephp.php" >
<input type="hidden" name="nombre" value=(name inserted before)>
<input type="hidden" name="nombre" value=(address inserted before)>
<select>
    <option value="i">$function_return[i]</option>
    <option value="i">$function_return[i]</option>
    <option value="i">$function_return[i]</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="second submit">
<form>
```

I have waste a lot of time... but im getting crazy.... could anyone save my life?

thanks

pd: adding the code i have tried:

```
<script>
function datos() {
var min = 0,
    max = <?php echo count(obtener("manuel")) ?>,
    select = document.getElementById('selectElementId');
for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.innerHTML = <?php echo obtener("manuel")[i][element] ?>;
    select.appendChild(opt);
}
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="datos()"/>;
</body>
</html>
<?php
function obtener($link) {
$buscar= (too large, simply it receives things, its only a practice exercise, i give to every name things like "color" "clothes" etc)
return $buscar;
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, could you post what php code you have, what is the output of $function_return etc...

Comment: I have tried to call a js which calls the function to get the count(array) and the elements... then using document.CreateElement but it doesnt work...

Comment: Javascript and PHP are executed in different places (client JS, server PHP) so you can't call a PHP function in JS because it runs somewhere else. You can invoke that function with an AJAX call and use the results of the call on the page to populate the select box.